# Retrieve data from the database when Search Button is click in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have editText's **(Username, Firstname, Lastname and Email Address)** in my activity for user registration. The user has the privilege to search if the username that he input is already existing or not, by clicking the **Search Button**. If the username is existing, all  the information with regards to that username like the name of the user will be showed. However, if the user click the button if it is not existing, my app crashes and I am getting CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException error. How can I debug that one?

MainActivity.java

```
btn_Search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String searchableUser = txt_User.getText().toString();

        ConsUserRegistration consUserRegistration = db.searchUser(searchableUser);

        String searchUser = consUserRegistration.getUser().toString();
        String searchFirst = consUserRegistration.getFirstName().toString();
        String searchLast = consUserRegistration.getLastName().toString();
        String searchEmail = consUserRegistration.getEmail().toString();

        txt_User.setText(searchUser);
        txt_First.setText(searchFirst);
        txt_Last.setText(searchLast);
        txt_Email.setText(searchEmail);             
    }
});
```

DatabaseHandler.java

```
public ConsUserRegistration searchUser(String username){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(Constants.TABLE_USER, new String[] {Constants.KEY_USER, Constants.KEY_FIRST, 
            Constants.KEY_LAST, Constants.KEY_EMAIL}, Constants.KEY_USER + " =? ", 
            new String[] { String.valueOf(username) }, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    ConsUserRegistration search = new ConsUserRegistration (cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));

    return search;

}
```

Comment: when it crashes you can get a stacktrace.  I think the crash is occurring in your databasehandler, as you try to access a cursor without even checking if it is null.  You check if it is null before moving to first but then access it no matter what.

Comment: So how can I code it without having the same error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

MainActivity.java

```
btn_Search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String searchableUser = txt_User.getText().toString();

        ConsUserRegistration consUserRegistration = db.searchUser(searchableUser);
        if (consUserRegistration != null){

           String searchUser = consUserRegistration.getUser().toString();
           String searchFirst = consUserRegistration.getFirstName().toString();
           String searchLast = consUserRegistration.getLastName().toString();
           String searchEmail = consUserRegistration.getEmail().toString();

           txt_User.setText(searchUser);
           txt_First.setText(searchFirst);
           txt_Last.setText(searchLast);
           txt_Email.setText(searchEmail);
        }else{
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }               
    }
});
```

DatabaseHandler.java

```
public ConsUserRegistration searchUser(String username){
    ConsUserRegistration search;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(Constants.TABLE_USER, new String[] {Constants.KEY_USER, Constants.KEY_FIRST, 
            Constants.KEY_LAST, Constants.KEY_EMAIL}, Constants.KEY_USER + " =? ", 
            new String[] { String.valueOf(username) }, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
            search = new ConsUserRegistration (cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
        }else{
            search = null;
        }

    return search;

}
```

Comment: I think it should be if (consUserRegistration != null){ since I am trying to get the value of the inputed and if the user didn't fill-out any, I should toast a message.

One more thing, I am not really familiar in error handling. Can you help me with that?

Comment: That is where you put your code if the username is availible.  In the above part you populate the textboxes with the user data if they exist.  In the error handling area, you do whatever you want to do if the username was not found. like `txt_User.setText("Not Found");` with all the boxes or something

Comment: @RanmaMarquee You were correct about the `!=` sorry was typing fast while putting the little one to sleep.  I can help you with error handling however we should go to a chat instead of in here so they do not flag the post as off topic. ALso I added the toast message to my post

Answer (score 1):

so... what happens if your cursor IS null or has no elements?  you're still trying to access it ...

Try something like...

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())  {    

...
```

Comment: i'm having an error since that method returning the value of my Constructor, ConsUserRegistration which is the 'search'

Comment: Your answer is only handles part of the problem, even though he checks before he accessing it now, it is trying to return a value that was never exsitant `search`, therefore the search function will still error out.

Comment: Read, not copy.  The main point is how you check your cursor.  If you just cut and paste what I wrote, it won't work.

Comment: I whittled the answer down to what you need to know as to not create any more confusion.